# Cannot connect to connecting to SQL Server 2008 from WSO2 Data services server on WSO2 Stratos live

Tags: sql-server-2008, wso2

I have started using WSO2 Stratos live and started using WSO2 data services server.

I am facing issue while using SQL Server 2008 with  WSO2 data services server.

I am getting below error

> The server version is not supported. The target server must be SQL
>   Server 2000 or later.

I believe the answer to this is to update the jars in Stratos live to use latest sqljdbc4.jar but I am not sure how to do it.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way that the users can replace the driver jars of the StratosLive Data Services Server and WSO2 should upload the latest versions of the jars to the server for you. We'll make sure they are updated soon.
As an alternative, if you want to have your own latest driver jars used, you can write a webapp including the desired jars inside WEB-INF/lib folder, host it in the WSO2 Application Server and connect to your MSSQL instance.

Regards,
Prabath

Comment: Thanks Prabath! I wanted to invoke WSO2 DSS from WSO2 ESB which is also on stratos live. I believe in this scenario it will not work. Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Is it possible to know when this update will be made?  I believe many people must be waiting for this update where ESB and DSS is used together

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying. We're in the process of upgrading the JDBC drivers of the StratosLive DSS node and it will be available in a few days time.